How to Select a Photo from the Gallery in a Kotlin Multiplatform Project
I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project targeting both Android and iOS, and I need to implement functionality to select a photo from the gallery. I've been trying to figure out the best approach to handle this in a shared codebase while utilizing platform-specific APIs for Android and iOS.
Here's the structure of my AddChildScreen composable where I want to include the photo selection feature:
@Composable
fun AddChildScreen(
    viewModel: UserViewModel,
    onBackClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    // ... other UI components

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
    ) {
        ProfilePhoto(
            photoHref = null,
            onEditClicked = { PickImageFromGallery() }
        )

        // ... other UI components
    }
}

My goal is to:
Define a common interface for the image picker in the shared module.
Implement the platform-specific code for both Android and iOS.
Could someone guide me through the steps to achieve this?

You could look at how https://github.com/onseok/peekaboo implements it.

Implementing the Image Picker can be tricky but there are two ways, you can achieve this. First way is to create expect & actual for native code and you can do that. Otherwise, You can use Some Libraries like Peekaboo & Other One is FileKt. Both Are Similar and easy to Use.
